# Set base path in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have just installed `cakephp3`. I have a folder mySite and in this folder I have run the command

```
`composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app `
```

CakePHP is installed in mySite/app folder. Now I when I access `localhost/mySite/app` it shows the main cakePHP page but without any styling. I have seen from firebug it is showing wrong path for `css` and `js` files. for example for css it is showing

```
localhost/mySite/app/bake.css
```

And I have seen it is `$this->Html()` helper. Now I want to know how can I set the base path of the application to webroot so that it automatically access files and assets from `webroot` folder. I have tried setting up `RewriteBase` in `app/.htaccess` and `app/webroot/.htaccess` as `RewriteBase /mySite/app` and `RewriteBase /mySite/app/webroot` respectively but nothing happened. How can I set this basic path for my application?

Second, If I have a .php file in `app/CustomScripts/scripts.php` path and I want to call that file in my controller, how can I do that. I have tried `require_once /app/CustomScripts/scripts.php` but it is giving file not found. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DocumentRoot of your web server to the `webroot` folder of your application.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot